# Consider a partition P

Tags: real-analysis, set-partition

Consider a partition $P= \{ [0,\frac{2}{7}]\}, \{ [\frac{2}{7}, \frac{1}{2}\}], \{ [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}]\}, \{ [\frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{7}]\}, \{ [\frac{5}{7},1]\} $ of $[0,1].$. Compute $\overline{I}_P(f)$ and $\underline{I}_P(f)$ for $f(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$

Now I know that:

A partition $P $ of $I$: $P=\{J_k: 0 \leq k \leq N\}$

$ l(J_k)=x_{k+1}-x_k$, where l is the length.

$\overline{I}_P(f)= \sum_{k=0}^N sup_{x \in J_k}f(x) \cdot l(J_k)$

$\underline{I}_P(f)= \sum_{k=0}^N inf_{x \in J_k}f(x) \cdot l(J_k)$

With this information, I'm having a hard time starting this solution. I can't find examples on computation of partitions, and I really want to understand how to do it.  Can someone provide an example similar to this or help me step by step?

Comment: Simply calculate the smallest (infimum) and largest (supremum) values of $f$ on each $J_k$, multiply by the length of $J_k$, and add them up. Which part specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Finding the length of $J_k$

Comment: That's just the length of each block. For example, $l(J_1) = \frac{2}{7} - 0 = \frac{2}{7}$, $l(J_2) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{7} = \frac{3}{14}$, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: So the length can be different for each block? So finding the pretty much is the infimum and supremum of each case times their respected length and just add them up?

Comment: Exactly, the length of a block is just the width of its interval.

Comment: Thank you @Alerra, is it possible for me to work on the problem and you can see if I went on the right direction?

Comment: Sure, also I will write up an answer to go along

Comment: Alright, i'll compare with my answer, and once more thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us find the $l(J_k)$'s. 
\begin{align*}
l(J_1) &= 2/7-0=2/7 \\ 
l(J_2)&=1/2-2/7=3/14 \\
l(J_3) &= 2/3 - 1/2 = 1/6 \\
l(J_4)&=5/7-2/3=1/21 \\
l(J_5) &= 1 - 5/7 = 2/7 \\
\end{align*}
Then the suprememum's (Because this seems to be a computation problem, I will simply use Wolfram Alpha):
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in J_1} f(x) &= 1/4 \\
\sup_{x\in J_2} f(x) &= 9/196 \\
\sup_{x\in J_3} f(x) &= 1/36 \\
\sup_{x\in J_4} f(x) &= 9/196 \\
\sup_{x\in J_5} f(x) &= 1/4 \\
\end{align*}

And now the infimum's:
\begin{align*}
\inf_{x\in J_1} f(x) &= 9/196 \\
\inf_{x\in J_2} f(x) &= 0 \\
\inf_{x\in J_3} f(x) &= 0 \\
\inf_{x\in J_4} f(x) &= 1/36 \\
\inf_{x\in J_5} f(x) &= 9/196 \\
\end{align*}

Then, multiplying and summing, we get (put answers as decimals so its easy to check):
$$
\overline{I}_P (f) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{7} + \frac{9}{196}\frac{3}{14} + \frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{6} + \frac{9}{196}\frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{7} = .1595... 
$$
and
$$
\underline{I}_P (f) = \frac{9}{196}\frac{2}{7} + 0\cdot\frac{3}{14} + 0\cdot\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{21} + \frac{9}{196}\frac{2}{7} = .0276... 
$$
Disclaimer: I kind of did this quickly so it is very possible I made a mistake somewhere in my calculations. Please call me out if you think I did that.

Comment: Looks good in my part.

Comment: Nice! Hope you understand the concept now.

Comment: Yeah, first time seeing it and without examples in my notes was kinda lost but now it's pretty clear. Thank you once again.